# OpenCV Boosting with Cross Validation

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

I trained a `cv::ml::Boost` classifier.  It gets 100% of most of the training set. The size of the trained file is approximately the same as the training data.
It seems as if it just basically keeps the whole training set so that it gets 100% on most of it.

Is there a way to measure its generalization ability? Maybe a way to do cross-validation or do I need to do that manually, by splitting my training data?

I'm using the similar parameters as in the `points_classifier.cpp` sample:

```
   auto boost = Boost::create();
   boost->setBoostType(Boost::DISCRETE);
   boost->setWeakCount(100);
   boost->setWeightTrimRate(0.95);
   boost->setMaxDepth(12);
   boost->setUseSurrogates(false);
   boost->setPriors(Mat());
   boost->train(trainingData);
   return boost;
```

If I call `boost->setCVFolds(10)` it crashes.

Comment: You should of course test your classifier against data which is not part of the training set.

Comment: Naturally, but cross validation as part of the training process should produce a better classifier.